# Stuck with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Can somebody find what is wrong with this code. It always returns o nodes no matter whatever XPath I chose

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
domFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dDoc = builder.parse("P:/MyBooks.xml");
NodeList myNodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//Title", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(myNodes.getLength());
```

MyBookx.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Books>
   <Title attrib="title1"/>
   <Title attrib="title2"/>
   <Title attrib="title3"/>
</Books>
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out or otherwise inspecting `dDoc` to make sure you actually have content in there? Also, what exactly does `xpath` refer to?

Comment: I have added XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); and your code works for me :) (prints 3).

Comment: Thank you guys for your support but I was doing another stupid thing. My actual doc was using default namespace while I am setting NamespaceAware(true) in docFactory. Now my problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing a big mistake. My xml doc was using default namespace while I am setting NamespaceAware(true) in docFactory. So I set NamespaceAware(false) and my problem is solved